# Build help menu for extensive BASH script

Tags: bash, menu, manpage

For a certain extensive BASH script I want to build a help menu, similar like the one you see when you run `mplayer --help` for example.

```
Usage:   mplayer [options] [url|path/]filename

Basic options: (complete list in the man page)
 -vo <drv>        select video output driver ('-vo help' for a list)
 -ao <drv>        select audio output driver ('-ao help' for a list)
```

What is the convention for using the different brackets `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` and other characters `|` etc? What is the conventional layout of such a menu? How do I explain the user witch options are mandatory?

There is probably a guideline somewhere, but I can not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface):

```
 - angle brackets for required parameters: ping <hostname>
 - square brackets for optional parameters: mkdir [-p] <dirname>
 - ellipses for repeated items: cp <source1> [source2...] <dest>
 - vertical bars for choice of items: netstat {-t|-u}
 - curly braces enclose mutually exclusive alternate values
```

Comment: This was indeed what I was looking for, but the answer is a bit concise. For example, what do the `{` and `}` do in your example? What is the correct way to build op the menu? How much do you indent the options? When do you use a single dash `-` and a double dash `--` for an option, etc. How do I build a help menu from scratch (the right way)?